# Changing the 'generate()'-method for a subclass of a class conforming to 'SequenceType'

Tags: class, swift, subclass, generator, sequence

Let's say I have a *generic class* `Parent<P>`, which conforms to the `SequenceType` *protocol*, by implementing the `generate()` *method*:

```
class Parent<P> {
    //...
}

extension Parent: SequenceType {
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<[P]> {
    //...

    return GeneratorOf<[P]> {
        //return the next element, or nil to stop
    }
}
```

Now the `generate()` method clearly doesn't simply return elements of type `P`, but `[P]`.

Now let's implement a subclass `Child<C>`:

```
class Child<C>: Parent<C> {
    //...
}
```

`Child` is also supposed to conform to `SequenceType`, but shouldn't return elements of type `[C]`, but rather `C`.
Logically I'd try to implement an own `generate()` method:

```
extension Child: SequenceType {
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<C> {
    //...

    return GeneratorOf<C> {
        //return the next element, or nil to stop
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though, and swift throws an error:

```
<stdin>: error: type 'Child<C>' does not conform to protocol '_Sequence_Type'
extension Child: SequenceType {
^
Swift._Sequence_Type: note: multiple matching functions named 'generate()' with type '() -> Child<C>.Generator'
func generate() -> Generator
^
<stdin>: note: candidate exactly matches [with Generator = GeneratorOf<C>]
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<C> {
^
<stdin>: note: candidate exactly matches [with Generator = GeneratorOf<[C]>]
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<[P]> {
^
<stdin>: error: type 'Child<C>' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
extension Child: SequenceType {
^
Swift.SequenceType: note: multiple matching functions named 'generate()' with type '() -> Child<C>.Generator'
func generate() -> Generator
^
<stdin>: note: candidate exactly matches [with Generator = GeneratorOf<C>]
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<C> {
^
<stdin>: note: candidate exactly matches [with Generator = GeneratorOf<[C]>]
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<[P]> {
```

What is the problem here, and how do I fix it?

---

#### Update #1:

So the problem seems to be fixed by applying @rintaro's approach of only defining a `typealias` for `Generator` in the `Child` *class*.
But as discussed in the comments by @AirspeedVelocity and @NateCook this is not a very viable approach, beacause the `Child` *class* could also be subclassed.

It was also stated that one could create an *instance property* (*computed* I assume) returning a *sequence* of the desired elements:

```
class Parent<P> {
    var asSequence: [[P]] {
        //some kind of getter
    }

    //...
}

class Child<C>: Parent<C> {
    override var asSequence: [C] {
        //some kind of getter
    }

    //...
}
```

The *instances* could then still be used in *for-in-loops*:

```
for element in someParent.asSequence {
    //element is of type [P]
}

for element in someChild.asSequence {
    //element is of type C
}
```

Would this be the *"best"* approach?

**Update #1.1:**

As @MichaelWelch suggested, the names of the *properties* (`asSequence`) could be confusing in this case, since they return different types.
This seems appropriate, but dependent on the situation. But generally ambiguity should be avoided.

Comment: I don't think inheritance is your best choice for solving this problem. While OO languages often let you overload a method with different signatures, many also have the constraint that you can't have the only difference in signature be the return type (Java, C# being two I know fairly well). Your child class is inheriting one generate method and you are trying to create another one with the only difference in signature being the return type.

Comment: You might consider having Parent have a method that returns a SequenceOf (rather than implement SequenceType itself). Then Child would inherit that method could add another method with a new name that returns a different SequenceOf. (The caller of these methods will need to know the difference anyway since the elements being returned are different)

Comment: It looks to me like the root error is that having two `generate` methods with different result types makes Swift infer two different type aliases for `Generator`, the alias that is a part of `SequenceType`. You can't override a type alias with a different type, so you get errors based on that conflict. @MichaelWelch's idea is a good one—don't make these conform to `SequenceType` directly, but instead have a method or computed property that gives access to the contents as a sequence.

Comment: @nate - I believe you can override type aliases: `class A { typealias T = Int }; class B: A { typealias T = String; func f() -> A.T { return 1 } }; println(B().f())` works fine (for certain definitions of fine :).  However I can't find a syntax for referring to B's T (`B.T` is ambiguous - presumably because `A.T` is also `B.T`). If there is such a syntax, maybe you could get the question's code to compile. However I'm with you guys that this is probably not something you should do...

Comment: Ah, so it's the ambiguity in the overriding method that's the problem: `extension A { func g() -> T { return 1 } }; extension B { override func g() -> T { return "a" } }` —> `'T' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`. If that's the case, should overriding a type alias be a compiler error? It basically poisons the type alias within the subclass.

Comment: Also leads to questions (even with structs) about how you could implement two protocols both of which required a typealias of the same name, but that needed to be aliased to different types.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I think I ran across the problem you are mentioning a few hours ago. I defined `protocol Something { typealias T }`, and wanted to extend Array to confrom to it, resulting in `extension Array: Something { typealias T = T`. This obviously didn't compile.

Comment: Regarding Update #1: I would not use the same method name `asSequence` in both parent and child. This would be very confusing to a consumer of your classes. I'd name it more descriptive so that in the Parent you know you are getting back a sequence of arrays of Parents, and in the child you are getting a sequence of children.

Comment: Well since `Parent` and `Child` were just examples, this doesn't apply to my actual code. There the parent class is a linked list returning its nodes, and the child an array returning its elements. Would the same property name be appropriate there?

Comment: @445646 I understand `Parent` and `Child` were just examples. I think the method names should try to explain why you are getting back different things. Perhaps `nodes` and `elements` for example; if that would make it obvious to a consumer that `nodes` is a sequence of arrays and `elements` is a sequence of all elements. If nothing else, by giving them different names there is no implicit reason to think they would return the same type of sequence. That alone would help ease the issue to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you can. Explicit typealias for `Generator` **only in** `Child` did the trick. However, I also think you *should not* do like this...

```
class Parent<P> {
    var _src:[[P]] = []
}

extension Parent: SequenceType {

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<[P]> {

        var g = _src.generate()

        return GeneratorOf<[P]> {
            return g.next()
        }
    }

}

class Child<C>: Parent<C> {
    var _ary:[C] = []
}

extension Child: SequenceType {

    typealias Generator = GeneratorOf<C> // <-- HERE

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<C> {

        var g = _ary.generate()

        return GeneratorOf<C> {
            return g.next()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, nice spot.  You're out of luck with grandchildren presumably :)

Comment: I would not want to maintain any code that consumes classes that use this trick. :-) Why do I sometimes get back a sequence of Child and sometimes a sequence of [Parent]??